# How do I add box shadows when the parent div has a background image?

Tags: css, html, background, dropshadow

I'm trying to set up a drop-shadow for a div with 2 columns of text. I have the basic structure:

```
<div class="box>
    <div id="container" class="pseudo-box">
        <p>This is a box</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css, below, seems like it should work, but whenever I un-comment the background image, whether it is in box or pseudo-box, the *before* and *after* boxes I want to use to create the shadow appear in the on top of pseudo-box, despite my z-indexes.   How can I fix this?

#### EDIT: No columns for simplicity, also JS Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rzZDD/

```
.box {
position: absolute;
top: 130px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
min-width: 850px;
bottom: 54px;
overflow: hidden;
/*  background: white url(/u/me/workspace/test2/webdesign/ribbon-horiz.png) top left no-    repeat;
*/ border-bottom: solid thin #aaaaaa;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 150%;
text-align: left;
z-index: 10;
background: white;
    
    }
    .pseudo-box{
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#cbcbcb), color-stop(100%,#bfbfbf)); 
        background: url(/u/me/workspace/test2/webdesign/ribbon-horiz.png) top left no-repeat;
        border: 1px solid #888888;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 10px;    
        position: relative;
    }
    .pseudo-box:before,
    .pseudo-box:after {
       content:"";
       position:absolute;
        z-index: -1;
       bottom: 10px;
       left:10px;
       width:50%;
       height:50%;
       max-width:300px;
       -webkit-box-shadow:0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
       -moz-box-shadow:0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
       box-shadow:0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
       -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
       -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
       -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
       transform:rotate(-3deg);
       background-image: none;
       
    }
    .pseudo-box:after {
       right:10px;
       left:auto;
       -webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);
       -moz-transform:rotate(3deg);
       -o-transform:rotate(3deg);
       transform:rotate(3deg);
    }

  #content {

position: absolute;
left: 20px;
right: 20px;
top: 40px;
bottom: 20px;
min-width: 650px;
padding: 0 10px 0 0;
overflow: auto;    
border-top: thin solid #aaa;
border-bottom: thin solid #aaa;
border-left: thin solid #aaa;
border-right: thin solid #aaa;
border-radius: 4px;  
/*      box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px 2px #aaa;
 */ 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set `z-index:1;` to parent it should allow pseudo-element to be under it without being underneath body.

`Overflow:hidden`, will cut things off .

`position:relative;` can be used to set from wich area , `absolute` child should take coordonates.

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/sLjEb

Solution is an extra element sticking at the bottom of the box that needed to be translucide. This extra element to draw shadow inside with overflow to only keep the part needed.
http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/bxiwL

Comment: Sadly I have tried this, and it does not work. Setting the z-index still keeps the pseudo-elements on top of the parent, even when the parent has a higher score. Again, this is only true when parent has a background image, which is what I want.

Comment: updated your fiddle too. you are abusing position:absolute where it is not needed. trust document flow and your browser a little more :)

Comment: Regarding positioning, fair enough. Have you tried your codepen with an image though? That's what still doesn't seem to be working. I tried adding an image via placekitten to my fiddle, but it does not work. 

And for anyone wondering, yes, this is my first attempt at web design.

Comment: background-color or background-image, isn't it the same ? So here it is with image in bg 'see pen updated)

Comment: So now make the box containing text transparent, so that the background bleeds through. Do that and my questioned is answered!

Comment: i guess this is where I misunderstand you. At this moment , background is a linear-gradient  for .pseudo_box (same as an image, replace it if you wish), .box has a background-image too, and html. Wich one is the one where you want a background-image. if pseudo_box, should it mixed with linear-grafient ?  some good info for you to start with :) . Else so many tutorial, i would not know wich to advise to you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32293/discussion-between-jefftopia-and-gcyrillus)

Answer (score 0):

One way to hack around this would be to supply a background-image with a gradient of white throughout, this can be achieved by:

```
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 0%, white 100%);
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jAg9j/6/

Comment: This doesn't seem to allow me to use a background image though. I'd like for the div containing text, ie psedu-box to basically be transparent with respect to the parent div, so that the parent div's background image is still visible.

Comment: @Jefftopia the background image is for .box or .pseudo-box? the css which you've supplied to us have the background-image present for both.

Comment: For box. Putting it on pseudo-box was a product of trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the shadows on the .box element rather than the .pseudo box like this:

```
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 850px;
  bottom: 54px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white url(/u/me/workspace/test2/webdesign/ribbon-horiz.png) top left no-repeat;
  border-bottom: solid thin #aaaaaa;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 150%;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 10;
  background: white;
}
.pseudo-box{
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#cbcbcb), color-stop(100%,#bfbfbf)); 
    /*background: url(/u/me/workspace/test2/webdesign/ribbon-horiz.png) top left no-repeat;*/
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 10px; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 20px;
    min-width: 650px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    border-top: thin solid #aaa;
    border-bottom: thin solid #aaa;
    border-left: thin solid #aaa;
    border-right: thin solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 4px; 
}
.box:before,
.box:after {
   content:"";
   display: block;
   position:absolute;
   background:#444;
    z-index: 0;
   bottom: 30px;
   left:40px;
   width:50%;
   height:50%;
   max-width:300px;
   -webkit-box-shadow:0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   -moz-box-shadow:0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   box-shadow:0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   -webkit-transform:rotate(-3deg);
   -moz-transform:rotate(-3deg);
   -o-transform:rotate(-3deg);
   transform:rotate(-3deg);
   background-image: none;

}
.box:after {
   right:40px;
   left:auto;
   -webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);
   -moz-transform:rotate(3deg);
   -o-transform:rotate(3deg);
   transform:rotate(3deg);
}
```